# Will I be able to restore previous backup after installing kubuntu?

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, backup

Last monday I made a backup using the default backup thing with Ubuntu. Today I made a mess: tried to just switch to kubuntu using sudo apt to get and install kubuntu desktop. Got system error. Rebooted laptop. Now after powering on it says I'm running on low graphical mode and it won't let me riconfigure graphics. By chance I hade a iso image of the latest kubuntu on a USB pendrive. If I install kubuntu will I be able to recover the backup I did on monday?

Comment: There are many types of backup. Please explain exactly how you made yours. More detail is better.

Comment: I just the backup tool that I found in ubuntu. Don't know if that helps.